# War file compresses resource file even in the exploded version

Tags: java, spring, war, wav, appfuse

I am packaging my Spring application into a war file to deploy to my tomcat server. When I put the war file in the tomcat6/webapps folder it auto-explodes, but some of my resource files still remain compressed.

For example I have a sinewave.raw and a audio.wav file in the src/main/resources folder. These files are available in the WEB-INF/classes/ folder in the war file, but they are still compressed and are corrupted.

Is there a better way I can package my project or store my resource files so that they are not corrupted when I deploy them.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that they are still compressed?

Comment: I guess the resources are corrupted before packaging into the war file. Just open it with the Zip-Tool of you choice and extract the resources to check this. Also check if there is enough space on the disk where you deploy.

Comment: I compared the size of the original file with the file I get after I deploy the file on the server. When I open the two files I can see that the deployed file is corrupted.

Comment: @Arne The resources before packaging are fine. I just checked the files again.

Comment: @ishan: "corrupted" != "still compressed"

Comment: @GregKopff right. Sorry for the confusion. The size of the resource file in the .war version and the exploded version is the same.

Comment: Are you using Ant to copy the media files and building war ? I faced similar issue and root cause of incorrect use of Ant copy task.

Comment: @Santosh I am using maven actually.

Comment: @ishan, In using Maven, are you using filtering of resources? Something like `<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>`